# Why can't I use the full resolution of my UltraSharp U2713HM with my macbook pro retina?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, resolution

I bought a Dell U2713HM because it was highly rated and had 2560x1440 resolution, but, after learning that the HDMI connection only provides 1980x1080, I purchased from Apple their Thunderbolt to DVI connector and tried that. Still 1980x1080. I've now ordered a mini-DisplayPort-to-DisplayPort connector and am praying that I get the full resolution that way, but I've seen a number of user group comments that you need a completely separate (over $100) Thunderbolt data (not display) interface to get the full resolution. If that's true, I'm returning the Dell. I've also seen people say you need to reset the PRAM and SMC settings, but I've tried doing that (I think it worked) but nothing changed.

HELP!

Comment: If you're not planning on using this monitor with any other computers, consider returning the Dell and replacing it with the Apple Thunderbolt 27" Display.  I've been using one for half a year with a late 2011 high-res, non-retina MBP 15" and its fabulous.  Same or similar price as the Dell.

Comment: I purchased the Dell monitor for about $500. The cheapest Thunderbolt 27" display I can find online is around $1,000 including tax. Still looking to find out if the mini-DP to DP cable will work. When I get it, I'll post the results.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, where did you find that Dell for $500?  That's a great price.

Comment: You can pick up a refurbished Thunderbolt Display from Apple for $799 USD. I purchased one, it had a dead pixel, so I headed to my local Apple Store. They replaced it with a brand new one. I had dozens on the Dell U2713HM that I had previously purchased. Dell gave me the runaround and I was lucky that Amazon refunded the purchase without a single hassle.

Answer (score 4):

get a Mini DisplayPort / Thunderbolt to DisplayPort Cable $17.99 or less, thats what i did works fine, although photoshop still displays non retina so have to scale to 50% which is a pain.

Comment: Dell U2713HM with iMac 27 Late 2013, this was the solution too, Thunderbolt -Mini Display Port on the iMac end and DisplayPort on the monitor side, neither the DVI nor the HDMI version worked, hope it would help for others fighting with this configuration too

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an ordinary DVI connection would be enough to reach a 2560x1440 resolution. For that you'd need a dual-link DVI connection, and in your case a mini-DisplayPort to dual-link DVI converter like [this one](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter). It costs $99, but you could probably get a generic Chinese clone on DealExtreme or eBay for much less. I can't speak for the mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort converter as I'm not familiar with the DisplayPort standard.

Comment: This is correct. Another option is to pick up a mini-display port to display port cable (Monoprice has them for around $10). Unfortunately, Dell doesn't provide the ability to reach the monitors full resolution out of the box. Absolutely deplorable if you ask me as LCD monitors aren't meant to run on anything but their standard resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Today I made this happen on my Mac Book Pro 15" Retina Late 2013 model by simply using a HDMI cable. Apparently recent version of HDMI supports 2560x1440 resolution...

You then have to configure you monitor to Not do any magic picture improvements and set Sharpness to 0 to avoid shadows and unclear text.

Answer (score 1):

Dell supplied their monitor (at least my U2312HM) with DVI Single Link cable. That's the reason why you have incorrect resolution and frame rate. 
To get higher resolution you need to buy DVI Dual Link cable (with 9 additional pins) to get support higher resolution and frame rate.

I sure that Dell made a mistake to supply the monitor with DVI Single Link cable.